# Use multiple @JsonView (Jackson) in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I want to use multiple JsonViews to serialize a response.
For example, I have the object below:

```
public class A {
        
    @JsonView(FieldView.A.class)
    private String a;
    
    @JsonView(FieldView.B.class)
    private String b;
    
    @JsonView(FieldView.C.class)
    private String c;
        
}
```

And I want to add on the serialization the views A and B. But I did not find any solution for that , because I'm using ObjectMapper writeWithView that accepts just one view (Not a List), this way if I add A then B and C are removed from the response.

```
om.writeWithView(FieldView.A.class)
```

Is that a way to writeWithView using more than one view?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I did a workaround. Using `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` I created a list of the fields I want to discard with `serializeAllExcept(Set<String> fields)`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(fields);
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", theFilter);
mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
```